# onClick blocking onFling

Tags: android

In my activity I have an imageView(at the top) and textView(at the bottom). Using both views I display an image and its corresponding description. I have implemented fling using 'SimpleOnGestureListener'..so that user can fling through different images and its corresponding description(on every fling, I load different image and show it to user).

Now the problem started when I added onClickListener for the ImageView( I need to detect onClick so that I can display a Toast with description of the image). But the onClick seems to be blocking the fling event. How do I detect fling.

Have already gone through the following questions(and few others) in this forum..

[android - giving onTouch priority over onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664756/android-giving-ontouch-priority-over-onclick)

[Android onClick blocking onFling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249036/android-onclick-blocking-onfling)

but still could not identify the solution.

Given below is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    ImageView m_imageView;
    String[] m_imageNames = { "img1__", "img2__", "img2__"};
    int m_index = 0;
    Resources m_res;
    Drawable m_drawable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Log.v("INFO", "Inside oncreate");

       m_imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       m_res = getResources();
       int imageId = m_res.getIdentifier(m_imageNames[m_index], "drawable", getPackageName());
       Drawable drawable = m_res.getDrawable(imageId);
       m_imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

       m_imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          Log.v("INFO", "Inside onClick");
       }
       });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     Log.v("INFO", "onTouchEvent detected");
     return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener
   = new SimpleOnGestureListener(){

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, 
        float velocityY) {
                //Fling code goes here
        }
   };

   GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(null, SimpleOnGestureListener);

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you took out of your code, but you have some serious bracket balance issues going on. Can you please fix those and update your code?

Comment: Sorry buddy for that...doing it(It becomes quite pathetic...when I copy the code form eclipse to here)..

Answer (score 0):

These methods generally have `boolean` returns, which indicate that this event has been consumed and should not propagate further. Try changing return values.